# Default verbatim styles for pythontex

Tags: pythontex

When using `\printpythontex` and the output `verbatim`, I'd like to set a default styling.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usefamily={jl,julia,juliacon},autoprint=false,autostdout=false,makestderr]{pythontex}


\begin{document}

\begin{jlblock}
A=[i+j for i=1:3,j=1:3]
display(A)
\end{jlblock}
\printpythontex[verbatim][frame=single,fillcolor=yellow,highlightlines={1-20},highlightcolor=yellow]

\end{document}
```

where I'm using julia as the language, but that shouldn't be relevant.

I'd like to have all (or nearly all) verbatim output have this style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\printpythontex` command with the `verbatim` option internally calls `\VerbatimInput` from the `fancyvrb` package. You can set default options for `\VerbatimInput` using `\RecustomVerbatimCommand`, as mentioned in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/doc/fancyvrb-doc.pdf) for `fancyvrb` on page 18 in a footnote.

MWE (converted to Python because I don't have Julia installed):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usefamily={jl,julia,juliacon},autoprint=false,autostdout=false,makestderr]{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}
{frame=single,fillcolor=yellow,highlightlines={1-20},highlightcolor=yellow}

%\begin{jlblock}
%A=[i+j for i=1:3,j=1:3]
%display(A)
%\end{jlblock}

\begin{pyblock}
for i in range(1,4):
   for j in range(1,4):
      print(i+j, end=" ")
   print()
\end{pyblock}
\printpythontex[verbatim]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]